# How to do base64 encoding/decoding when using CloudFront function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, encoding

Amazon CloudFront Function is a new feature introduced by AWS. 
CloudFront Function can be written using JavaScript only. 
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-cloudfront-functions-run-your-code-at-the-edge-with-low-latency-at-any-scale/

Our website generates a timestamp and encode it using btoa() (Base64 encoding). 
Then, website sends HTTP GET request which includes the encoded timestamp to CloudFront function.

```
var sending_time        = new Date().getTime();
var enc_sending_time    = btoa(sending_time);

function generate_http_request(enc_sending_time)
{
...
}
```

Once CloudFront function receives the HTTP request, 
it should decode the timestamp using atob().

However, CloudFront Function does not support atob().
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-javascript-runtime-features.html

**How can we do base64 encoding to an integer 

and then do base64 decoding on CloudFront function side 

without using btoa() and atob()? (JavaScript only)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudFront does not support btoa() and atob() functions, 
so we cannot do Base 64 encoding/decoding using these functions.

So as an alternative, we can use the following: 
https://gist.github.com/oeon/0ada0457194ebf70ec2428900ba76255

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

CloudFront [adds a few non-standard methods](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-javascript-runtime-features.html), including one to string to decode from base64:

`var decoded = String.bytesFrom(str, 'base64');`

It also accepts `base64url` for encoded versions.

They show this in [an example which decodes JWTs at the edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/example-function-validate-token.html).

Unfortunately they don't seem to have the equivalent to do base64 encoding.